# Rails3: Searching for Users by Second nad First name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to write a simple search method in my User model where it checks agisnt the Second name and first name and returns matching users. I have this at the moment but throws an error:

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where("first_name like ? or second_name like ?", "%#{search}%")
    else
      all
    end
  end
```

the error is: `wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2) in: first_name like ? or second_name like ?`

How can i fix this?

Thanks

Comment: my guess is that you'd need `def self.search(first,last)` and then put both of those in your dohickey at the end of your `where` clause. Don't really know Rails, but that's where I'd start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two `?` which means the `where` method is expecting two arguments:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where("first_name like ? or second_name like ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
  else
    all
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if you can streamline those `like`s to use one argument instead of the duplicate two, but you could clean it up a little:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    q = "%#{search}%"
    where("first_name like ? or second_name like ?", q, q)
  else
    all
  end
end
```

Comment: this doesn't work, i don't think it should be marked as true.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
where("first name like :name or second name like :name", :name => "%foo%")
```